# Java: call a method with name stored in variable

Tags: java, selenium

I have a requirement such that:

```
String command = "click";   // this can have value such as clear, getLocation, getSize, getTagName etc. 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options); //creating a webdriver object
driver.findElement(By.id("id1")).click(); //Here I want "click" method should be called dynamically as per what I have stored in variable `command`.
```

So, is there something possible like:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id1")).<something to call click()>
```

I have already looked at Reflection in Java, but that looked to me complex as per my requirement. Any pointers will be helpful!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use reflection:

```
String command = "click";
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id1"));

Method method = WebElement.class.getMethod(command);
method.invoke(element);
```

If you also want to call `By.id` with reflection, then you can do this:

```
String command = "click";
String id = "id";

Method byMethod = By.class.getMethod(id, String.class);
WebElement element = driver.findElement((By) byMethod.invoke(null, "id1"));

Method method = WebElement.class.getMethod(command);
method.invoke(element);
```

Comment: I am really sorry as I am asking another question in same question.

What if my `id` is also stored in a variable. For example, a variable containing `id` or `xpath` based on which I have to take action:
`driver.findElement(By.<coming from variable value>("id1")).<something to call click()>`
In this situation, how can your solution be extended ?

Comment: @OmSao I have changed the code a little and added an answer for you second question. Please tell me if this code works because I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 22):

Your variable represents something you want to do with a web element (in this case, click on it).

The appropriate type for that is not `String`. Use a `Consumer<WebElement>` instead (or whatever the type of what `driver.findElement()` returns is):

```
Consumer<WebElement> command = e -> e.click();

// ...

command.accept(driver.findElement(By.id("id1")));
```

This is type-safe, efficient, refactorable, and much more flexible than reflection (since your consumer can do whatever it wants with the element, not limited to a single method call without any argument. Like for example, enter some text in a text field)

Comment: good point, there could be a `Map<String, Consumer<WebElement>` to fetch a needed consumer by a command name

Comment: Hi JB: So, as per you, I have to mention`click` during assignment of `Consumer<WebElement>` ? 
If I want to invoke commands like `clear`, `getLocation` etc , then again I have to define explicity like
`Consumer<WebElement> command = e -> e.clear();`

Am I correct, or I am missing something ?

Comment: Yes. Just like you would have to change `String command = "click";` into `String command = "clear";`. Except you'd be sure to actually use a method that exists, your IDE would provide auto-completion, you could pass arguments (i.e. `Consumer<WebElement> command = e -> e.sendKeys("hello");`).

Comment: Actually I am reading the value of variable `command` from somewhere, so I don't know what value it can have.

Also, I am really sorry as I am asking another question in same question.

What if my `id` is also stored in a variable. For example, a variable containing `id` or `xpath` based on which I have to take action:
`driver.findElement(By.<coming from variable value>("id1")).<something to call click()>`
In this situation, how can your solution be extended ?

Comment: Regarding the first part: then parse your command into a Consumer<WebElement>: i.e. "click" is parsed to `e -> e.click()`, "text_hello" is parsed to `e -> e.sendKeys("hello")` for example. Regarding the second part, use an object containing a Consumer<WebElement>, and a `By` instance, allowing to find the element to consume.

Comment: This is a great answer, but it's important to note that it doesn't cover the case of `getLocation()` or similar methods.  That said, even if you made a   `Function<WebElement, X>`, the `X` parameter is different for each method, so there's no good way to deal with those functions.

Comment: In some cases this can even be shortened a little bit more by using method references, e.g. Consumer<WebElement> command = WebElement::click;

Comment: @user1932890 Yes, this is the ideal scenario for a method reference as it is semantically exactly what the variable is meant to store.

Answer (score 5):

In terms of design(and probably this can be further optimized and abstracted for sure), you can probably define an `Enum`, let us name it `Action` as:

```
public enum Action {
 CLICK,
 SENDKEY,
 etc
}
```

In your code then do:

```
Action action = <input>;
// find the element
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id1"));
switch(action) {
    case CLICK:
        element.click();
        break;
    case SENDKEY:
        element.sendKey();
        break;
    ...
    default:
        System.out.println("Undefined action");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to build a keyword-driven framework. To be honest, I'd be very surprised to hear any successfull story on that. Was always wondering what's the real purpose of such kind of frameworks? Who gonna use it? Managers, manual QAs or stakeholders? For me it makes no sense to involve non-tech persons in test automation activities. Any automation requires good tech skills (including programming and devops). Otherwise, failure probability is quite high.

Anyway, your question is more about `strings` vs `functional interfaces` mapping, or very smart reflection usage. But the main problem is that you've chosen wrong API [inputs] for that. The following line:

```
driver.findElement(locator).doSmth();
```

is a right way to fail, as `findElement` uses implicit waits. And I'm 100% sure that you'll start global refactoring / revising implemented approach, when you face with `NoSuchElementException` / `StaleElementReferenceException`.

Common sense suggests using fluent waits with `ExpectedConditions`. But it'll make your task even more complicated, as besides locators and actions you have to think about conditions, which should be supplied by the users.

From technical point, I'd create common wrappers first to encapsulate low-level WebDriver API calls. It'd be much easier to map or reflect such functions in comparison with raw calls. E.g. expected conditions could be hidden on enum level:

```
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public enum WaitCondition {

    visible(ExpectedConditions::visibilityOfElementLocated),
    enabled(ExpectedConditions::elementToBeClickable);

    private final Function<By, ExpectedCondition<WebElement>> type;
}
```

It'll be easy to retrieve required constant by calling e.g. `WaitCondition.valueOf("visible")`, where input string could be passed from outside.

Common API wrapper may look like the following then:

```
protected void click(By locator) {
    click(locator, enabled);
}

protected void click(By locator, WaitCondition condition) {
    waitFor(locator, condition).click();
}

private WebElement waitFor(By locator, WaitCondition condition) {
    return wait.until(condition.getType().apply(locator));
}
```

Mapping / reflection examples were already provided by others in this thread. Just a note: if you prefer reflection, I'd recommend you to look at [jOOR](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOR) library, which simplifies this process.